# How to Show Different Info in C++ Using proc/cpuinfo

Tags: c++, linux, function, ubuntu, cpu

I am new to C++ and am trying to write a shell script. I would like to be able to show different information based on user input. For example when a user types cpuinfo -n they should get the number of cores, and if they type cpuinfo -c they should get the clock speed. I however don't really know how to get clock speed or Type of processor from cpuinfo.
I am struggling with getting all of this information. I have been able to get the number of cores in a function, but I would like to be able to get different information all in one function using a switch perhaps. That way my code wouldn't need three different functions all opening up proc/cpuinfo.
Here is my code that relates to this so far:

```
int cpuInfo(void) {
    FILE *cmd = popen("grep '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l", "r");

    if (cmd == NULL)
        return -1;

    unsigned nprocs;
    size_t n;
    char buff[8];

    if ((n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff)-1, cmd)) <= 0)
        return -1;

    buff[n] = '\0';
    if (sscanf(buff, "%u", &nprocs) != 1)
        return -1;

    pclose(cmd);

    return nprocs;
}

int execute_Commands(string args[]) {
    if (args[0] == "exit") {
        useShell = false;

        if (args[1] == " ")
            return 1;
        else
            return stoi(args[1]);
    }

    else if (args[0] == "prompt") {
        if (args[1] == " ")
            prompt = "cwushell> ";
        else
            prompt = args[1];

        return 1;
    }

    else if (args[0] == "cpuinfo") {
        if (args[1] == "-c")
            cout << "Clock Speed: " << endl;
        else if (args[1] == "-t")
            cout << "Type: " << endl;
        else if (args[1] == "-n")
            cout << "Number of Cores: "<< cpuInfo() << endl;
        else
            cout << "cpuinfo manual" << endl;

        return 1;
    }
```

Would there be a way to change cpuInfo() to take in an argument and return either the number of cores, cpu type, or clock speed?

Comment: You could pass an integer (`0`, `1` or `2`) to correspond to the data you want to fetch. Then you have an array of the commands you pass to `popen`, and use the integer as an index into this array to get the correct command, To improve the code change the integer to an enumeration. Oh, and don't forget to add some validation for the values passed.

Comment: Thank you for your input, could I use a switch for this? Also I am struggling on how to display clock speed and cpu type

Comment: As long as you only have a handful of alternatives. But what I would *really* recommend is to use different functions for doing different things.